# Uploading Documents (DOC/DOCX) to Rails with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I need to allow my users to upload Word Documents (.doc files) to my application. Images and PDF's work fine, but when I try to upload a document, I'm getting:

```
undefined method `documents_path'
```

Here's the code in my Document.rb file.

```
      validates :title, presence: true
      validates :file,
        attachment_content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "application/pdf", 'application/msword','applicationvnd.ms-word','applicaiton/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingm1.document', 'text/plain']},
        attachment_size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

      has_attached_file :file, styles: {
        thumb: '100x100>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '350x350>',
        pdf_preview: '600x600>'}, processors: [:thumbnail]
```

Here's my view:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@document, multipart: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, :label => "Name of Document" %>
    <%= f.input :hotel_id %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, :label => "Upload Document" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

And my Routes:

```
resources :hotels do
    resources :advertisers
    resources :documents
end
```

Comment: Show your view and routes.rb

Comment: @Yule Added Views and Routes to my Question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass @document, which is a Document, rails looks up a route for documents_path, which doesn't exist because you've nested it inside hotels. You'll need to specify the hotel as well:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@hotel, @document], multipart: true) do |f| %>
  ...
```

remember to define `@hotel`

Comment: Thanks but this is not the problem. The document is bypassing the "if @document.save" action in the controller, and falling into the else section. Any ideas? PDFs and IMGs/GIFs work perfectly.

Comment: I couldn't possibly comment without seeing the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a bit late but after encountering the same problem i found a solution that worked for me. Just put the following inside a document called (or create it) **config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", :docx
```

And the docx uploads should work with the content_type quoted.

Now if anybody is interested for uploading only *pdf*, *doc* & *docx* as i was, just put the following in your model

```
validates_attachment_content_type :your_column_name, :content_type => ['application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']
```